# HoloLens 2 Not Retaining Anchor Placement

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, azure-spatial-anchors

we're using the HoloLens 2 and Azure world anchors to place the content within a room but when viewing the app content the anchors/room are  spun 90% or 180% from where they should be. They are always square on and never diagonal, so it's like the room is being flipped.

We’re confident it's not the code, as we've successfully used it in multiple other locations, it just this one room we can't get it to work in.

To ensure it’s not our code we’ve tried rebuilding the app, as well as ensuring we’re on the latest versions of Unity and MRTK. The HoloLens 2 firmware are also up-to-date and we’ve also tried adding a delay to the code, just in case the network's too fast and it needs some latency to do it’s thing but none of this has helped.

Additionally, the anchors stick in a position for 5-20mins, then will move to a new position - so occasionally they seem to be working but even a broken clock is right twice a day!
There’s no consistency across headsets either and the anchors will be a different position for each one. The app and code is rock solid in all other locations and we've tested placing the content on another wifi network and the same wifi network but another location and all works as it should. We've tried removing all and nearby holograms to refresh the spatial map but this  doesn't cure the issue. We've also tried making the room less complex as well as more complex but again this doesn't fix things and if it does it's only temporary.

Our gut feeling is it’s something out of our control, such as  wifi points throwing it out of whack, or interference of some kind such as magnetic or radio etc. If it's useful or relevant we also use Photon to facilitate a shared experience across devices.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to walk around a bit in your room to map it out more .. also of the room (at least the known map parts) look to similar to the HL2 (e.g. empty room with square dimensions) + GPS tracking etc bad this might happen as well

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. We have tried that. The room wasn’t empty but we were having the issue so emptied it. I don’t believe the HoloLens uses GPS but then MS have been vague about how it works. Will try different room configurations to see if that helps but I have a feeling it won’t and something else is causing the issue.

Comment: Some rooms are very hard to map correctly. This is because the features collected in the spatial anchors are quite coarse. Also you have to keep in mind they are related to medium size geometrical features. So if your room does have roughly the same geometry features in either direction, they will flip sometime. Source: I have worked with Azure spatial anchors for an extended period if time.

Comment: Also no, HoloLens does not have GPS. You need to play close attention to which anchors are being found and how.
Sometimes you have one ancher that is way more error prone than others, because the features stored in it are to generic or repetitive, and because other anchors are then found be relation it screws them up too.

Comment: Thanks @ephb much appreciated! The room is rectangular and quite long but not square. It was separated by sections of temporary walling to create walk ways. We've increased and reduced the complexity of the room but the issue persists.

Do you have any suggestions on what we could do to the room to help, such as place objects in there?
 
We also learnt that the HL uses wifi spots to map a space, and there's multiple dotted around, could this be causing us issues?

Comment: @Philgoo it does not actually use wifi for actually relocating. Only for querying for the SpatialAnchors it could use to relocate. It then uses the features in these possible anchors to locate one anchor and it automatically places others which where created in the same session.
[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/anchor-relationships-way-finding) explains it a bit more.
Sometimes you will run into situations where you are creating **one** anchors which holds futures that are so generic, that this will be found in multiple locations in your room. I

Comment: I suggest you turn on the highest level of logging to see which anchor is actually causing this wrong relocation [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/logging-diagnostics). 
If you have issues connecting to HoloLens for capturing the log output I have used [SRDebugger](https://www.stompyrobot.uk/tools/srdebugger/) in the past with great results to deliver logs.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments and help so far @ephb - we do have debugging tools on and it shows that the coordinates are different for each headset. We’ll also look further into the links you’ve supplied. 

Could interference be the cause of our issues? Such as metallic lights across the whole room, which are literally right next to the router in the ceiling?

Comment: @Philgoo No, absolutely not. Sorry if that was maybe not clear but wifi is never actually used for relocating. It is only used to query the api for a list of anchor ids that are then passed to the watcher process for relocating. So even if your wifi was disturbed that would at most influence the query.

Comment: @Philgoo one way to debug this would be to adjust your app in a way where you limit the relocation step to one anchor at a time and check which ones are relocated correctly.

Comment: @ephb We have tried that but unfortunately the same issue occurs, none of the anchors (even one on its own) stays in place for any length of time sadly and they all move to obscure positions. It works for a while then changes. Does the room spatial map in the headset matter when placing for anchor? i.e. if the headset or another headset maps the room differently? We've not had issues before but wondering if the room needs to be scanned each time? Also do flat walls cause a problem when mapping and placing anchors?

Comment: Hi @ephb & derHugo thanks for both your help, it's been very useful. 
Even after some detailed room mapping, placing 1 anchor at at a time & adding more detail to the room, the issue persisted. Our guess is it's room size, shape, lack of detail and anchor positions throwing others out. What we did find is if the 1st anchor is placed successfully, all other anchors then fall into place - this now works 100% of the time. This was discovered via a neat app we built that allowed us to place 1 anchor at a time, or all anchors at once. We'll now add this as a setup process to the start of our app.